# pysvn - trac: commit to svn and reference a trac system by url

Tags: svn, trac

Is it possible to commit a python file to svn and reference a trac ticket from a trac system other than the trac system the svn repository is linked to? Using refs #ticketnumber it automatically updates the trac ticket from the system linked to the repository. I have the url for the trac ticket i want to link to.

I cant really change anything on the backend for this, only the python file that i'm commiting.

Answer (score 0):

Do you just want to create a link from your local Trac instance to the remote Trac instance, or do you want the remote Trac instance to have a CommitTicketUpdater comment with a changeset reference? You cannot do the latter with Trac, or with any plugins that I'm aware of. In theory you might be able to write a plugin to do that, but it might be a lot of work.

If you just want a hyperlink to the remote Trac instance from your local Trac instance, you could use an [InterTrac](https://trac.edgewall.org/wiki/InterTrac) link. You need to define the InterTrac prefix on the system that you are committing to, however. The InterTrac prefix can be defined on the local system by editing it's trac.ini file.

After the InterTrac prefix is defined, you could write `Refs othertrac:#1` to reference ticket #1 in `othertrac`. Actually, the `Refs` isn't even needed.

If you can't edit trac.ini, or even have an administrator to edit it for you, you might be able to use an [InterWiki](https://trac.edgewall.org/wiki/InterWiki) link. The InterWiki links are defined by editing the `InterMapTxt` page on your local Trac instance.